# Getting Syntax Error While Inputting Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use a shortcode in a php file using the do_shortcode function but I keep getting a syntax error in the shortcode part.

This is the actual error:

> PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'success'
>   (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in your code on line 1

I tried to edit the code myself and tried to fix it using several syntax help websites.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[epcl_box type="success"]test[/epcl_box]"); ?>
```

I am not sure why I get the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong use of quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[epcl_box type="success"]test[/epcl_box]"); ?>
                        ^               ^       ^                ^
```

Escape the inner quotes:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[epcl_box type=\"success\"]test[/epcl_box]"); ?>
                                         ^^       ^^
```

... or use single quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[epcl_box type="success"]test[/epcl_box]'); ?>
                        ^                                        ^
```

Comment: They could also use single quotes instead of escaping them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Double quotes in type="success" you have to use single quote instead as it is breaking your string:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[epcl_box type='success']test[/epcl_box]"); ?>
```